# Iterating KeyValueCollection?

Tags: jsp, key-value

I have a function which return in the form of a KeyValueCollection, How to iterate it to get the key and value in jsp... Any suggestion????

Comment: There is a method in the api tat we are using... we can iterate the key value using that... Sorry to bother!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the jstl tags as follows. The tag library should be on your jsp imports

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${applicationScope}">
    Name:  ${entry.key}
    Value: ${entry.value}<br>
  </c:forEach>
```

Comment: I cannot use a jstl tag... suggestion in jsp please...:(

Comment: Then do the same as you would do in a normal Java class. This is not related to JSP then.